# Why does my import projection in adf dataflow rename the columns in a weird format?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

Why does my import projection in adf dataflow rename the columns in a weird format?

[image]

While resetting the schema of the data flow source infers the columns as follows (this is also the desired outcome of the import projection button):

[image]

Most probably because of this mismatch I can't review the data when I go to the Data Preview tab and press the refresh button.

Also when I import the schema from the dataset (similar to lower snapshot) , the result is different from the import projection in the source of the dataflow (upper snapshot).

Anything would help.

Answer (score 0):

This is my sample data:

[image]

I got similar issue in dataflow projection when I tried in my environment.

[image]

This happens when you didn't select the correct encoding in the dataset.

[image]

I have changed the Encoding from `UTF-16LE` to `UTF-8`.

[image]

And now it is working fine for me.

[image]

As your data didn't have any special characters, go through the encodings and select proper encoding as per your data. For me `UTF-8` is working fine.